# Why is the tabBar still black even after I set opaque to NO, alpha to 0, and color to clear?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

As above, I can't seem to change the background color or image of the tabBar. Even when hiding it by changing alphan 0, I still see it as a black solid bar.

How can I fix this?

Comment: you can customize the tab bar with the appearance API in iOS 5

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code:

```
[tabBar setHidden:YES];
```

If you're trying to set an image for the background, try this:

```
[tabBar setBackgroundImage:myImage];
```

Comment: Curious if you've verified this works. Plus the docs say "You should never attempt to manipulate the UITabBar object itself stored in this property." Sounds like that would apply to setting `hidden` (if it works) but maybe I'm missing something ...

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing behind the tab bar. The views of the view controllers that tab bar controllers manage do not extend into the area occupied by the tab bar.